# Access directly to object declared into fxml file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm pretty new to `Java FX` and `fxml` templates, I know that to access to an object's methods you need to use `setOnAction` and declare a specific method into the controller class.
Is there a way to access to its methods from code without using `setOnAction`?

Example what I want to do:

FXML Document

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="package.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="myLabel" text="Label" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Controller class

```
    public class Controller {
    @FXML
    Label myLabel;

    public Controller() {
        this.mylabel = new Label();

        //some code here

        myLabel.setText("modified text 0");

        //some code here

        myLabel.setText("modified text 1");
    }
}
```

Is that possible in some way by not using `setOnAction` custom method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JavaFX, is binding an alternative to action-listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610581/in-javafx-is-binding-an-alternative-to-action-listener)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example that shows what you are trying to do? Can't you just inject the control into the controller using [`@FXML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation) and call methods on it there as needed?

Comment: Do you mean accessing the controller instance, for a loaded FXML file?

Comment: @James_D Added example

Comment: 1. Don't create a new label: you presumably want to use the label created in the FXML file, not one you just create on the fly. 2. The `@FXML`-annotated fields won't have been initialized when the constructor is invoked (how could they?). Call the methods in the `initialize()` method instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785417/javafx-fxml-controller-constructor-vs-initialize-method (Also look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation).)

Comment: If you want to access to your methods ,implements initializable interface and call your methods from initialize() method.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine It has not been necessary to implement `Initializable` since JavaFX version 2.1.

Comment: @James_D if i try `initialize()` method I get NullPointerException

Comment: Then something else is wrong somewhere.